# How do I determine the previous value of a variable?

Tags: excel, vba

I generated values for a variable using a for loop.

Is it possible to subtract a previous value of that variable from the current value of that variable?

I tried using offset but it doesn't work (probably because offset can only be used for ranges right)

```
Function test(Price As Range)
    Dim Pos, Neg, Count, MF_ratio, MF_index, Tar_price, Flow As Long

    Dim day As Range

    For Each day In Price

        Tar_price = (day.Value + day.Offset(0, -1).Value + day.Offset(0, -2).Value) / 3

        Flow = Tar_price * day.Offset(0, 2).Value

'This is where the problem starts, I want to compare the previous value stored in the variable 'Flow' with the current value stored in 'Flow'

        If Flow.Value > Flow.Offset(-1, 0).Value Then

            Pos = Pos + Flow

    Next day

    test = Pos
End Function
```

Update:
[image]

I'm trying to sum up the money flow (column K) for the past 14 entries if the current row's money flow is greater than that of the previous row.

```
Function test(Price As Range)
Dim Pos, Count, Tar_price, Flow, Old_flow As Long
Dim day As Range
Count = 1
For Each day In Price
    Tar_price = (day.Value + day.Offset(0, -1).Value + day.Offset(0, -2).Value) / 3
    Old_flow = Flow
    Flow = Tar_price * day.Offset(0, 2).Value
    If Count > 1 Then
        If Flow > Old_flow Then
            Pos = Pos + Flow
        End If
    End If
    Count = Count + 1
Next day
test = Pos
```

Comment: Hi. U need to have a second variable to store the previous value.

Answer (score 1):

Not directly.  What you need is a second variable that you pass the old value into before replacing it:

```
Dim Flow As Long, OldFlow AS Long

' Some of your code here...

OldFlow = Flow 'Save the old value
Flow = Tar_price * day.Offset(0, 2).Value

' More of your code here...

If Flow > OldFlow Then 'Compare old with new

    Pos = Pos + Flow

End If 'This line is VERY important!  Do not forget it!
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks so much for helping me out :) I tried your method, but for some reason I end up with the wrong numbers for some rows (highlighted in yellow), I've attached a link to a photo of the spreadsheet: https://i.stack.imgur.com/66RhQ.png, what I'm trying to do is to sum up the money flow (column K) for the past 14 entries if the current row's money flow is greater than that of the previous row. I really have no idea what went wrong with my code, sorry to trouble you with it!

Answer (score 0):

you could turn `Tar_price` to a Function accepting `day` range as parameter to which you can add that `Offset(-1)` when needed:

```
Function test(Price As Range)
    Dim Pos As Long, Neg As Long, Count As Long, MF_ratio As Long, MF_index As Long, Flow As Long
    Dim day As Range

    For Each day In Price
        Flow = Tar_price(day) * day.Offset(0, 2).Value
        If Flow > Tar_price(day.Offset(-1, 0)) * day.Offset(-1, 2).Value Then Pos = Pos + Flow
    Next

    test = Pos
End Function


Function Tar_price(day As Range) As Long
    Tar_price = (day.Value + day.Offset(0, -1).Value + day.Offset(0, -2).Value) / 3
End Function
```

BTW 1: you must explicitly declare all variables type or they will be assumed of `Variant` type

BTW 2: seems like you don't need `Neg`, `Count`, `MF_ratio` and `MF_index` variables at all